# Python smtplib: Unable to send sms messages to phone

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to send messages to my phone using the SMTP protocol. If I log into my Google Account (for which I've [enabled less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1)) I'm able to send a message to '5551234567@tmomail.net'. The subject and body of the email arrive on my phone as a text message.

However, when I try to do the same with Python's `smtplib` library, I don't get a message. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import smtplib

# Establish a secure session with gmail's outgoing SMTP server using your gmail account
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)

server.starttls()

# the account that will send the emails
server.login('me@gmail.com', 'password')

# sendmail(from, to, msg)
server.sendmail('me@gmail.com', '5551234567@tmomail.net', 'hey there!')
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get the text message to come through from the `smtplib`? Any suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check the link below.

If seems like you for forgot

server.ehlo()

[How to send an email with Gmail as provider using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python)

Please let us know if you see python message in SENT emails folder of Gmail Inbox.

If yes, try to find a differences between one you sent from browser and one you sent from python API.