# How to send form information to my personal email?

Tags: python, django

I built a website in Django, I have a form that stores the information of my clients in my database, but I want that when a person sends their info I receive an email with their information instead of checking my database data.

Comment: Have a go before asking someone else to do it for you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/

Answer (score 0):

In case that you want to use Gmail account, check this:
[How to send an email with Gmail as provider using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python)

The general doc. info is on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/

Answer (score 0):

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

s = smtplib.SMTP(' ')#smtp server like Gmail, outlook 
s.set_debuglevel(1)
msg = MIMEText("""body""")
sender = ' '#your email ID in string
recipients = [' ', ] #recipient's email must be in list
msg['Subject'] = "subject line"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = recipients
s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
```