# How to send python code output over email?

Tags: python

I have an output of `df['sentiments']` as sentiment output of twitter tweets. I want to mail that sentiment output over email to another person automatically.

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: [Tutorial on sending emails in Python](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the python built in library smtplib:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html to send emails.

You can use, for example the GMAIL mail server to send it.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/send-mail-from-your-gmail-account-using-python

Answer (score 1):

Store it in a file using `df['sentiments'].to_csv('sentiment.csv')`. And send the file `sentiment.csv` via mail.

More details about `to_csv` function can be found [here in the official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

EDIT: Expanding the answer for the sake of making it less troublesome. [Credits for this part](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/)

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
mail_content = '''Sample message'''

#The mail addresses and password
sender_address = 'sender@gmail.com'
sender_pass = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
receiver_address = 'receiver@gmail.com'

#Setup the MIME
message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = receiver_address
message['Subject'] = 'A test mail sent by Python. It has an attachment.'  

#The body and the attachments for the mail 
message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))

filename = "database.txt" #- Attach the sentiment.csv and metadata file here

# Open PDF file in binary mode
with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
    # Add file as application/octet-stream
    # Email client can usually download this automatically as attachment
    part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(attachment.read())

# Encode file in ASCII characters to send by email    
encoders.encode_base64(part)

# Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
part.add_header(
    "Content-Disposition",
    f"attachment; filename= {filename}",
)

# Add attachment to message and convert message to string
message.attach(part)

#Create SMTP session for sending the mail
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) #use gmail with port
session.ehlo()
session.starttls() #enable security
session.login(sender_address, sender_pass) #login with mail_id and password
text = message.as_string()
session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
session.quit()
print('Mail Sent')
```

If you get an error as follows:

`(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials y186sm1525057pfy.66 - gsmtp')`

Follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python/27515833#27515833)

Comment: Ok if we want to add multiple outputs along with it then what should be the process? i meant along with it user_name and follower count of user and send it!?

Comment: Do you want this information in the output file or separately? The right approach should be to send the data as one file and the additional information as an addendum in a `Readme.md` file or a `metadata` file.

Comment: @nikhildasoju do you want to send the mail automatically using python or that is to be done manually?

Comment: i want email to be sent automatically.

Comment: Then you can use the steps in my answer followed by @Serbitar's answer to get your work done. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No i need the output itself to be sent as mail rather than saving it into csv and then sending it automatically.

Comment: Then you can ignore the attachment part and simply add all the data in the `mail_content ` variable. It will do the job!!!

Comment: You meant adding outputs in a variable named "mail_content"?

Comment: Yup!! If you go through my code, you will find the variable in the 6th line.

Comment: You can consider upvoting the answer if it helped.