# Giving error when trying to send a email with smtplib in python 3.8.3

Tags: python, smtplib

I gives me a error when I run the program or try to update smtplib. This is the error:

[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z0uS.png)

I am using python 3.8.3. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
# from your Gmail account  
import smtplib 

# list of email_id to send the mail 
li = ["example2@gmail.com(email)", "example3@outlook.com(email)"] 

for dest in li: 
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
    s.starttls() 
    s.login("example1@gmail.com(email)", "example1(password)") 
    message = "Message_you_need_to_send"
    s.sendmail("example1@gmail.com(email)", dest, message) 
    s.quit()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Auto_Email/Auto_Email3.py", line 16, in <module>
    server.login(username,password)
  File "C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 734, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 723, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 646, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials d9sm5982379qtq.56 - gsmtp')



PS D:\Auto_Email> pip install update smtplib
Collecting update
  Using cached update-0.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.9 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement smtplib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for smtplib
```

I have already tried to update smtplib (show above) and tried different usernames and passwords and all give me the same error. I have also allowed access on my google account.

Comment: Post all errors and code here directly as text as an [mcve] if possible.

Comment: It kept on marking it as spam when I put the code and error message in it.

Comment: It was likely telling you that you require more explanation of your problem and what you've already tried to solve it.

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-send-emails-with-gmail-using-python/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send an email with Gmail as provider using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python)

Comment: It gives me a different error than what he had, plus I do not have a vpn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still having problems you need to first go to the google accounts security setting and allow unsecured apps to access the account.[image: The setting]