# Python AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute '_create_stdlib_context'

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I am trying to send email (Gmail) using python, but I am getting following error:

> 'AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute '_create_stdlib_context'

My code:

```
def send_email(self):
    username = '****@gmail.com'
    password = '****'
    sent_to = '****@gmail.com'

    msg = "Subject: this is the trail subject..."
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
    server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(username, sent_to, msg)
    server.quit()
    print('Mail Sent')
```

The following is the error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.8 /Users/qa/Documents/Python/python-api-testing/tests/send_report.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/qa/Documents/Python/python-api-testing/tests/send_report.py", line 23, in <module>
    email_obj.send_email()
  File "/Users/qa/Documents/Python/python-api-testing/tests/send_report.py", line 11, in send_email
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1031, in __init__
    context = ssl._create_stdlib_context(certfile=certfile,
AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute '_create_stdlib_context'
Start of /Users/qa/Documents/Python/python-api-testing/tests/send_report.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this may be based on how you're forming the SMTP messages. They broadcast in batch, kind of the way FTP, and HTTP does; but the following should help:

```
import smtplib
USR = #<username@domain.tld
PWD = #<Password>


def sendMail(sender, receiver, message):
    global USR, PWD

    msg = '\r\n'.join([
        f'From: {sender}',
        f'To: {receiver}',
        '',
        f'{message}',
    ])

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(USR, PWD)
    server.sendmail(msg)
    server.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sendMail('sender@dom.tld', 'receiver@dom.tld', 'This is a test, of the non-emergency boredom system.')
```

[Python3 Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example) indicate some error handling to be aware of, but the original idea I based this code around can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python). Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Jesse for the solution, I have tried the same but it didn't resolve the issue. Still Encountering the mentioned Error
```
  server.starttls()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 772, in starttls
    context = ssl._create_stdlib_context(certfile=certfile,
AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute '_create_stdlib_context'
```

Comment: Did you make sure to run an `ehlo` before running the `starttls`?