# Coding C# Visual Studios Email

Tags: c#, email, c#-4.0

im struggeling to use visual studios coding in C# to be able to email from a project, getting plenty errors, what should i do and can somebody help me code a program that can email in c# please.

here is my code that doesnt work:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

    mail.From = new MailAddress("intergratedpoolproducts@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("brandonjubber46@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Test run 101";
    mail.Body = "This is an automated emailing service";
    smtp.Port = 465;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(mail);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: "Everything, expected it to work but it doesnt." What doeas that mean? Do you get any errors? Please be as specific as possible about what you expect to happen and what you recognize instead.

Comment: It runs just doesnt send the email at all, dont have an answer for my problem, i googled and asked chatgpt.

Comment: I believe this is considered a *"Less Secure App"* and no longer supported by google. OAuth would definitely work, you could try this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/72626684/591285. On a side note, I wouldn't spoof the from address to avoid spam.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the error but as far as I understand you didn't set the DefaultCredentials property to false:

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; //ADD THIS LINE TO YOUR CODE
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");
```

Be aware to add this code line before you set the credentials!

Also you should enable 2 Step Verification. After the enable set App Password to use your gmail in 3rd party programs. [Check this out to enable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72577189/gmail-smtp-server-stopped-working-as-it-no-longer-support-less-secure-apps/72626684#72626684)

If none of these help your problem change Port to 587:

```
smtp.Port = 587;
```

Comment: I added your line and changed the code a bit, it runs now but it doesn't send the email at all

Comment: @BrandonJubber change port to 587 and also you should enable 3rd party programs to use your gmail adress. I edited the answer check that.

Comment: thanks i did that, but google doesnt allow you to enable 3rd party programs since may 2023, thats where im struggeling badly.

Comment: @BrandonJubber Check the link again you need to get app pasword. After receiving your app pasword you will use that as your password on setting credentials.

Comment: Thanks i did that, but third party programs where removed from google in may of 2023, thats where i think my issue is lying

Comment: Yes i know that. To use your gmail in 3rd party programs firstly you should enable 2 Step Verification. After the enable you should set App Password and use that app password in your credential.