# PHPMailer not sending emails - SMTP Configuration Issue

Tags: php, email

#### Question

I am facing an issue with PHPMailer where it doesn't seem to be sending emails. I've set up a simple registration system, and the verification email using PHPMailer is not reaching the intended recipients. I've included the relevant code below:

```
<?php
// Include PHPMailer autoloader
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

// Include configuration
include 'config.php';

// Function to sanitize input
function sanitizeInput($input) {
    return htmlspecialchars(trim($input), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

// Function to send verification email
function sendmail($to, $subject, $verificationCode) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // Set true for exceptions

    try {
        // Configure SMTP settings
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com'; // Use the full Gmail address here
        $mail->Password = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        $mail->Port = 587;  // Adjust the port if necessary
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Add this line

        // Set email parameters
        $mail->setFrom('example@gmail.com', 'APIForm');
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        // Styled HTML body
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = '
            <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    body {
                        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                        background-color: #f4f4f4;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 20px;
                    }
                    .container {
                        max-width: 600px;
                        margin: 0 auto;
                        background-color: #fff;
                        padding: 20px;
                        border-radius: 5px;
                        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
                    }
                    h1 {
                        color: #333;
                    }
                    p {
                        color: #555;
                    }
                    .verification-code {
                        font-size: 24px;
                        font-weight: bold;
                        color: #3498db;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Account Verification Code</h1>
                    <p>Dear user,</p>
                    <p>Your verification code is: <span class="verification-code">' . $verificationCode . '</span></p>
                    <p>Thank you for registering!</p>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
        ';

        // Send the email
        $mail->send();

        // Email sent successfully
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Email not sent
        return false;
    }
}

// Function to handle registration API
function register() {
    global $pdo;  // Make $pdo variable available in this function
    $subject = "APIForm Account Verification";

    // Assuming you receive registration data in the POST request
    $firstname = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? sanitizeInput($_POST['firstname']) : null;
    $lastname = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? sanitizeInput($_POST['lastname']) : null;
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? sanitizeInput($_POST['email']) : null;
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? sanitizeInput($_POST['password']) : null;
    $confirmPassword = isset($_POST['confirm_password']) ? sanitizeInput($_POST['confirm_password']) : null;

    // Check if all required fields are provided
    if ($firstname && $lastname && $email && $password && $confirmPassword) {
        // Check if passwords match
        if ($password === $confirmPassword) {
            // Check if the email already exists in the database
            $stmtCheckEmail = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts WHERE email = ?');
            $stmtCheckEmail->execute([$email]);
            $emailExists = (bool)$stmtCheckEmail->fetchColumn();

            if (!$emailExists) {
                // Generate a unique user token using uniqid
                $userToken = uniqid('user_', true);

                // Generate a 6-digit code
                $verificationCode = sprintf('%06d', mt_rand(0, 999999));

                // Sending verification email
                if (sendmail($email, $subject, $verificationCode)) {
                    // Hash the password for security
                    $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

                    try {
                        // Insert data into the accounts table using a prepared statement
                        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO accounts (userToken, firstname, lastname, email, password, creationDate, code) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?)');
                        $stmt->execute([$userToken, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $hashedPassword, $verificationCode]);

                        // Respond with a success message
                        $response = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Registration successful', 'userToken' => $userToken);
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error inserting data into the database');
                    }
                } else {
                    $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error sending verification email');
                }
            } else {
                $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Email already exists. Please use a different email address.');
            }
        } else {
            $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Passwords do not match');
        }
    } else {
        $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'All fields are required');
    }

    // Send JSON response
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}

// Function to handle login API
function login() {
    global $pdo;  // Make $pdo variable available in this function

    // Assuming you receive username and password in the POST request
    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

    // Check if both username and password are provided
    if ($username && $password) {
        try {
            // Fetch user information from the database based on the provided username (email)
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, userToken, firstname, lastname, email, creationDate, password FROM accounts WHERE email = ?');
            $stmt->execute([$username]);
            $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if ($user) {
                // Verify the provided password against the hashed password stored in the database
                if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
                    // User logged in successfully
                    $response = array(
                        'success' => true,
                        'message' => 'Login successful',
                        'user' => array(
                            'id' => $user['id'],
                            'userToken' => $user['userToken'],
                            'firstname' => $user['firstname'],
                            'lastname' => $user['lastname'],
                            'email' => $user['email'],
                            'creationDate' => $user['creationDate']
                        )
                    );
                } else {
                    $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid credentials');
                }
            } else {
                $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'User not found');
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error retrieving user information');
        }
    } else {
        $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Username and password are required');
    }

    // Send JSON response
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

I've ensured that the SMTP configuration for Gmail is correct in the `sendmail` function, and I've also checked for any exceptions during the email sending process. However, the emails are not being delivered.

I suspect there might be an issue with the SMTP settings or some other configuration. Could someone please review the code and help me identify what might be causing this problem? Are there any common pitfalls with PHPMailer and Gmail SMTP that I might be missing?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72577189/gmail-smtp-server-stopped-working-as-it-no-longer-support-less-secure-apps

Comment: Are those credentials in the code real? If so, you've just shared them with the world and should change the password on that e.ail address _immediately_

Comment: Your question is confusing. First you say: _"I've ensured that the SMTP configuration for Gmail is correct"_, but in the next paragraph you say: _"I suspect there might be an issue with the SMTP settings or some other configuration"_. Which is it? Have you ensured the settings are correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    // Set up the mail sender
    $mail->setFrom('your_email@gmail.com', 'Your Name');
    $mail->addAddress('recipient_email@example.com', 'Recipient Name');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Your Subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'Your HTML email body goes here';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Your plain text email body goes here';

    // Set up the SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port     = 587;
    $mail->Username = 'your_email@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'your_email_password';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;

    // Send the email
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Email has been sent successfully.';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Note that you should enter your real email addresses and passwords in lieu of the placeholders "your_email@gmail.com," "your_email_password," and "recipient_email@example.com," among others.

Additionally, keep in mind to manage the exception appropriately in order to receive the precise error message in the event that the email cannot be sent.

Finally, ensure that your require statements contain the correct path to the library if you choose to utilise PHPMailer.

Code Explanation: The given code sends an email via Gmail's SMTP service by using PHPMailer. Email data are set up, including the sender's and recipient's addresses. Any exceptions that might happen while sending an email are caught by the script.

Modifications Made: The code you gave was already well-organized. I didn't alter anything really noteworthy. I made sure that the Exception, PHPMailer, and SMTP PHPMailer classes were included appropriately.

Why These Modifications: It is essential that the necessary PHPMailer classes are included for the script to run correctly.Considering that the code was created as a simple template for delivering emails using PHPMailer, your original question did not require any significant changes.

Comment: When writing an answer and post some code, make sure you include an explanation of the code, what you've changed and why.

Comment: Erikson and Adyson Yes, sir. I will revise my response to make it more understandable for everyone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy