# send mail with smtp python with more options

Tags: python

Here is

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
```

I want to make it more customizable with additional parameter of `timeout` and `port`.

I want to send email using SMTP python with the port that runs on any host (but don't want to use port 25 ) and I'm unable to set out `timeout` on it.

Comment: may be this link help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505/sending-mail-from-python-using-smtp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting `port` and `timeout` ?

```
 smtplib.SMTP(server, port=1234, local_hostname='your_local_host', timeout=10)
```

Or tried reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP)?