# Send e-mail to Gmail with inline image using Python

Tags: python, image, email, gmail, mime

My objective is to use Python to send an e-mail to a Gmail user that has an inline image. It is not possible to host this image online and then link to it through a `href`, due to the sensitive nature of the images (data from my work).

I've tried encoding the `base64` version into a `HTML` then sending th is `HTML`, but this is well known to not work. I then noticed that in Gmail you can drag and drop an image into the send box and it will show up inline in the receiving end. Given this I then tried to send an e-mail from Python with the image as an attachment. This is seen in the below code, but unfortunately the image doesn't show up inline.

My question is then: **How to send the image such that it shows up inline?**

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders
import os

gmail_user = "user1@gmail.com"
gmail_pwd = "pass"

to = "user2@gmail.com"
subject = "Report"
text = "Picture report"
attach = 'TESTING.png'

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = gmail_user
msg['To'] = to
msg['Subject'] = subject

msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
Encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
   'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(attach))
msg.attach(part)

mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
# Should be mailServer.quit(), but that crashes...
mailServer.close()
```

When I send the inline image to myself manually this is what the "original email" looks like:

```
  Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=047d7bd761fe73e03304e7e02237

--047d7bd761fe73e03304e7e02237
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=047d7bd761fe73e03004e7e02236

--047d7bd761fe73e03004e7e02236
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

[image: Inline images 1]

--047d7bd761fe73e03004e7e02236
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<div dir="ltr"><img alt="Inline images 1" src="cid:ii_141810ee4ae92ac6" height="400" width="534"><br></div>

--047d7bd761fe73e03004e7e02236--
--047d7bd761fe73e03304e7e02237
Content-Type: image/png; name="Testing.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <ii_141810ee4ae92ac6>
X-Attachment-Id: ii_141810ee4ae92ac6
```

When I send it to myself through Python as an attachment it is very different:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============6881579935569047077=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
(.... some stuff deleted here)
--===============6881579935569047077==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

See attachment for report.
--===============6881579935569047077==
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="TESTING.png"
```

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but I put together a easy mailing class for stuff like this, since myself I need to use it every now and then http://datamakessense.com/easy-scheduled-emailing-with-python-for-typical-bi-needs/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It seems that following the gmail email template works:

```
* multipart/alternative
  - text/plain
  - multipart/related
    + text/html
      <img src="cid:msgid"/>
    + image/png
      Content-ID: <msgid>
```

Based on the example from [`email`  module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html#email-examples):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import html
import mimetypes
from email.headerregistry import Address
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import make_msgid
from pathlib import Path

title = 'Picture report…'
path = Path('TESTING.png')
me = Address("Pepé Le Pew", *gmail_user.rsplit('@', 1))

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Report…'
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = [me]
msg.set_content('[image: {title}]'.format(title=title))  # text/plain
cid = make_msgid()[1:-1]  # strip <>    
msg.add_alternative(  # text/html
    '<img src="cid:{cid}" alt="{alt}"/>'
    .format(cid=cid, alt=html.escape(title, quote=True)),
    subtype='html')
maintype, subtype = mimetypes.guess_type(str(path))[0].split('/', 1)
msg.get_payload()[1].add_related(  # image/png
    path.read_bytes(), maintype, subtype, cid="<{cid}>".format(cid=cid))

# save to disk a local copy of the message
Path('outgoing.msg').write_bytes(bytes(msg))
```

To send `msg` via gmail:

```
import smtplib
import ssl

with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', timeout=10) as s:
    s.starttls(context=ssl.create_default_context())
    s.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    s.send_message(msg)
```

#### Python 2/3 compatible version

```
* multipart/related
  - multipart/alternative
    + text/plain
    + text/html
      <div dir="ltr"><img src="cid:ii_xyz" alt="..."><br></div>
  - image/jpeg
    Content-ID: <ii_xyz>
```

Based on [Send an HTML email with embedded image and plain text alternate](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/473810-send-an-html-email-with-embedded-image-and-plain-t/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cgi
import uuid
import os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text      import MIMEText
from email.mime.image     import MIMEImage
from email.header         import Header    

img = dict(title=u'Picture report…', path=u'TESTING.png', cid=str(uuid.uuid4()))

msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
msg['Subject'] = Header(u'Report…', 'utf-8')
msg['From'] = gmail_user
msg['To'] = ", ".join([to])
msg_alternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg.attach(msg_alternative)
msg_text = MIMEText(u'[image: {title}]'.format(**img), 'plain', 'utf-8')
msg_alternative.attach(msg_text)

msg_html = MIMEText(u'<div dir="ltr">'
                     '<img src="cid:{cid}" alt="{alt}"><br></div>'
                    .format(alt=cgi.escape(img['title'], quote=True), **img),
                    'html', 'utf-8')
msg_alternative.attach(msg_html)

with open(img['path'], 'rb') as file:
    msg_image = MIMEImage(file.read(), name=os.path.basename(img['path']))
    msg.attach(msg_image)
msg_image.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(img['cid']))
```

To send `msg` via gmail:

```
import ssl

s = SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', timeout=10,
             ssl_kwargs=dict(cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                             ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
                             # http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
                             ca_certs='cacert.pem')) 
s.set_debuglevel(0)
try:
    s.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], [to], msg.as_string())
finally:
    s.quit()
```

`SMTP_SSL` is optional, you could use `starttls` method from your question instead:

```
import smtplib
import socket
import ssl
import sys

class SMTP_SSL(smtplib.SMTP_SSL):
    """Add support for additional ssl options."""
    def __init__(self, host, port=0, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_kwargs = kwargs.pop('ssl_kwargs', {})
        self.ssl_kwargs['keyfile'] = kwargs.pop('keyfile', None)
        self.ssl_kwargs['certfile'] = kwargs.pop('certfile', None)
        smtplib.SMTP_SSL.__init__(self, host, port, **kwargs)

    def _get_socket(self, host, port, timeout):
        if self.debuglevel > 0:
            print>>sys.stderr, 'connect:', (host, port)
        new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
        new_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(new_socket, **self.ssl_kwargs)
        self.file = getattr(smtplib, 'SSLFakeFile', lambda x: None)(new_socket)
        return new_socket
```

Comment: How would I add text in the same e-mail as the image?

Comment: Look at the MimeText calls in the code: they add plain text and HTML bodies in the first argument. You may write whatever you like there

Comment: (you're missing an ``import os``)

Comment: @ABM: do you see `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top? (the code works with `'…'` on both Python 2 and 3)

Comment: Using the python3 version of the code I get the mail but the image doesn't show up, I just get the alternate. Anyone else has this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add the following lines:

```
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

body = MIMEText('<p>Test Image<img src="cid:testimage" /></p>', _subtype='html')
msg.attach(body)


img = MIMEImage(image.read(), 'jpeg')
img.add_header('Content-Id', '<testimage>')
msg.attach(img)
```

`testimage` should be replaced with a unique identifier