# Preventing Reverse DNS lookup by gmail while sending mail using python

Tags: python, smtp

I am trying to send messages on gmail using python. What I did was following:

```
>>> import smtplib
>>> session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
```

But just after this step, it got stuck i.e. it is not being able to connect to the server.
I searched this up on google and found out that gmail actually does a reverse dns lookup and doesn't allow a connection if a domain is not found. 
Is there a way to prevent gmail from doing this reverse lookup or something equivalent which helps me in sending messages using python?

Comment: This code in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272134/sending-email-does-not-work-when-i-run-the-script-but-line-by-line-it-works-w) and answers show basically how do this.

Comment: Are you authenticating with your email credentials before sending the mail or just trying to deliver the mail to some random gmail account. Gmail will do `Reverse DNS lookups` only for the latter one.

Comment: @clement89 Authentication is the next step.

Comment: So if you are authenticating with `SMTP.login(user, password)` before sending mail, Gmail will not be doing Reverse DNS checks.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763455/how-to-send-a-mail-directly-to-smtp-server-without-authentication

Comment: @clement89 Assuming that SMTP is a variable as the format is generally some_Variable.login(_,_), for initialising the variable we first need to run 'some_Variable = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com","587")'.