# Executing shell mail command using python

Tags: python, email, process, subprocess, popen3

I have used the following code to send an email as suggested in one of the post on the similar topic. But the mail has not been sent. Any suggestions?

```
import subprocess
recipient = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
subject = 'test'
body = 'testing mail through python'
def send_message(recipient, subject, body):
    process = subprocess.Popen(['mail', '-s', subject, recipient],
                               stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.communicate(body)

print("sent the email")
```

Comment: Did you call the function send_message()?

Comment: Does `mail -s ...` work from the command-line on your machine? If not; `subprocess` won't make it work. You could [send email using `smtplib`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20787826/4279)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your function may not be called, try this code :

```
import subprocess

recipient = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
subject = 'test'
body = 'testing mail through python'

def send_message(recipient, subject, body):
    try:
      process = subprocess.Popen(['mail', '-s', subject, recipient],
                               stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    except Exception, error:
      print error
    process.communicate(body)

send_message(recipient, subject, body)

print("sent the email")
```

May works. Good luck.

Comment: Seeing the below error if run in windows
    
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Scripts/sending_gmail_3.py", line 12, in <module>
    send_message(recipient, subject, body)
  File "C:/Python34/Scripts/sending_gmail_3.py", line 10, in send_message
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1111, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: @sandy Of course. The `mail` command does not exist in Windows.

Comment: In Python 3.x, change to `body = b'testing mail through python'` to work

Comment: @iqhcpsgbl = how can we add attachment in the above example? I need to attach csv...