# Running a system command through python not producing the same output

Tags: python, subprocess, postfix-mta

Ok so this incredibly weird thing happened. I am running a python script to produce some output and store it in a file. At the end of the script, I am using subprocess module to send a mail via postfix. I run

```
subprocess.call(['sudo mail -s "Subject" person@example.com < /path/to/file.txt'], shell=True)
```

This executes but gives the message `mail: Null message body; hope that's ok` even though the file has contents. And I receive an email with no body (but correct subject).

When I run the command directly:

```
sudo mail -s "Subject" person@example.com < /path/to/file.txt
```

I receive the contents of the file in the email.

What is going wrong here? It has totally messed up my head!

Comment: First, make sure you launch the Python script using sudo. Also, have you tried splitting the list you pass to subprocess.call? (['sudo', 'mail', '-s', "Subject", person@example.com, '<', '/path/to/file.txt'']

Comment: I don't think running it as with sudo is going to help. You see I am still receiving the mail, just the body is missing.

Comment: Piping the text file into `mail` on standard input would be somewhat safer, and would hopefully allow you to avoid `sudo` completely, as well as remove the need for `shell=True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected, it was an utterly stupid error (These are the best ones).

I wasn't flushing my file handle and sending the mail. So the message body was empty. Now I am using

```
file_name.flush()
file_name.close()
subprocess.call(['sudo mail -s "Subject" person@example.com < /path/to/file.txt'], shell=True)
```

and the mail I receive has the body. Phew!

Comment: you could [pass input to the child process using `Popen.communicate()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/163542/4279). Or just [send email using pure Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20787826/4279)