# Storing return data of print Whois in Python

Tags: python, email, whois

I have this Python script:

```
import whois 
w = whois.whois('google.com')
print w
```

I want to store the results of print to send them via an email.

Comment: What have you tried so far?, you can see here how to send email via python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505/sending-mail-from-python-using-smtp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) to make your life a lot easier for sending an email.

Run on commandline `pip install yagmail`

Next, you can easily send an email to yourself like:

```
import yagmail
import whois 
w = whois.whois('google.com')

yag = yagmail.SMTP('yourusername@gmail.com', 'yourpasswrd')
yag.send(contents = str(w))
```

Note that the default is to send to yourself without a `to` argument.

If you want to be explicit you can do:

```
yag.send('recipient@email.com', "this is the subject", str(w))
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have your results stored in `w`.