# ImportError: cannot import name SMTP_SSL

Tags: python, python-2.7, email

I am trying to send emails from the python script following this thread [Sending mail from Python using SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505/sending-mail-from-python-using-smtp)

But I am getting an error while doing this:

```
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL as SMTP
```

Error: ImportError: cannot import name SMTP_SSL

I am using python2.7.10 and I downloaded it from https://www.python.org/downloads/

Can anybody guess what can be the reason for the error. Please note that the name of script is not email.py

Comment: Is your script called email.py or do you have a file with that name in your directory?

Comment: May not be very helpful, but the python code from the Sending Mail link works (gets past the import) on python 2.7.8 32-bit on Windows x64.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has been solved as I created a file email.py previously but after finding related issues I created another file with different name

But I found that even the presence of email.py in the directory causes problem. After deleting the email.py the script is not causing any issue in running

Comment: I got the same problem and I fixed it just by changing the name from email.py to a different one.

Answer (score 1):

**NEVER EVER CREATE YOUR FILENAME WITH 'email.py'** that's gonna cause a lot of issues.
I was facing the same issue and as I rename the file the problem got sorted out.
The issue could be with the same name as python could have an inbuild email module. 
I was trying to import the below modules

```js
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that while you may have downloaded and installed Python 2.7.10, you're actually running a version of python earlier than 2.6 when you execute `python` from the command line.

Can you execute:

```
python -V
```

And post the results?