# Email alert if file doesn't exist - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to python.

I have a folder called "etc" with a filename password.txt when generates every night. I would like to run a python script in windows task on daily basis to check if password.txt doesn't exist then send email to abc@ouremail.co.uk else do not send any email.
I want to trigger email based on the below condition. When the condition is "false" send email else no action taken. How can I achieve it, any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

> > os.path.isfile("/etc/password.txt")
> >     True

Kind regards,

Biswa

Comment: post the code you have tried

Comment: you can use the [task schedualer](https://www.jcchouinard.com/python-automation-using-task-scheduler/) to scheduale your script to run daily. you can use smtplib to send eails, [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/send-emails-using-code-4fcea9df63f/) is an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check if File Exists using the os.path Module

The os.path module provides some useful functions for working with pathnames. The module is available for both Python 2 and 3

```
import os.path

if os.path.isfile('filename.txt'):
    print ("File exist")
else:
    print ("File not exist")
```

Then to send an email you can use smtplib (one topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505/sending-mail-from-python-using-smtp))

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'me@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'you@gmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'simple email in python'
message = 'here is the email'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
# identify ourselves to smtp gmail client
mailserver.ehlo()
# secure our email with tls encryption
mailserver.starttls()
# re-identify ourselves as an encrypted connection
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.login('me@gmail.com', 'mypassword')

mailserver.sendmail('me@gmail.com','you@gmail.com',msg.as_string())

mailserver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way i can specify file format like *.txt instead of specifying the name of the file?

Comment: Then [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) is what you need
`import glob
if glob.glob('*.csv'):
    print ("File exist")`