# Why is my Python SMTPLib email script not working and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, email, gmail, gmail-api, smtplib

So I used a [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxFXnLEmnb4) to write a basic Python email script. The comments said that the video was very helpful, yet my code is not working.

My code looks like this

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
import ssl
import smtplib

email_sender = 'correctemail@gmail.com'
email_password = "corr ectp assw ords"

email_receiver = 'throwaway@email.com'

subject = 'Written by Code!'
body = """
    This was written by my program! Tell me if it worked.
"""

em = EmailMessage()
em['From'] = email_sender
em['To'] = email_receiver
em['Subject']
em.set_content(body)

context = ssl.create_default_context()

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context) as smtp:
    smtp.login(email_sender, email_password)
    smtp.sendmail(email_sender, email_receiver, em.as_string())
```

The Error looks like this:
`smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed`

Does anybody know why it failed and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If how you send the email does not matter, perhaps this other Stack Overflow question may help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505/sending-mail-from-python-using-smtp

This specific method may or may not work, but other simpler methods definitely do.

Comment: Thanks! I have no clue how to distinguish between the ways to send the email... I just want an email sent from correctemmail@gmail.com to throwaway@email.com that contains simple text...

Comment: @Bird is it typo `"stmp.gmail.com"`? should be `smtp` i guess

Comment: I'M AN ACTUAL IDIOT-- well now i get `smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed my problem. I had to switch `smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context)` for just `smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')`

I don't know why it worked